# Intercept and stub third party <script> tags with Cypress

Tags: cypress

my use case: Testing a third party widget on a website.

For that, we load the widget on the third party as a `<script src='https://cdn.com/widget.js'/>` tag. What I'd like to do is intercept that JS request and replace `https://cdn.com/widget.js` with `https://localhost:3000/dist/widget.js`.

This is so that we can run the cypress tests with the local version of the widget (run in CI on a PR), and make sure that the PR doesn't break the e2e tests, before merging it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the body of the initial visit using `cy.intercept()`

```js
cy.intercept(url, (req) => {
  req.continue((res) => {
    res.body = res.body.replace('https://cdn.com/widget.js', 'https://localhost:3000/dist/widget.js')
  })
}).as('page')

cy.visit(url)

cy.wait('@page')
  .its('response.body')
  .should('contain', "<script src='https://localhost:3000/dist/widget.js'/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [blockHosts](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#blockHosts) to prevent the script at that domain from loading completely. That won't let you replace it with a fake wdiget though.

In order to replace the response with something else, you could use [Intercept](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept#Syntax) instead.

There's an interesting example of using this and `stub` to replace Google Analytics here - https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/stubbing-spying__google-analytics

Comment: I don't want to `stub` the response though, I would just like to point the request to a different `src`, to run the tests against the local version of the widget

Comment: Why not read the contents of https://localhost:3000/dist/widget.js from disk into part of the intercept command? 

Either that or use a different build config as part of your CI pipeline to load in a different script tag, and not use Cypress to do this.

Comment: @RYFN Because of that open issue https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1271